# In which locale, we can sort an string column in postgresQL such that the upper case and the lower case are mixed

Tags: postgresql

In which locale, we can sort an string column in postgresQL such that the upper case and the lower case are mixed. 
For instance, the sorted order might be [a, A, b, B] instead of [A,B,a,b].

Comment: The easiest way is to use `order by lower(the_column)`

Comment: It does not work here. There are other fields in each tuple. I want to sort them in exact order.

Answer (score 0):

Locales are provided by the underlying system, not by PostgreSQL itself, so this question is more about your (unspecified) OS than postgres.

Anyway a lot of locales should be expected to sort both `a`,`A` before `b`, `B`.

Example on Linux/glibc:

```
select * from (values ('a'),('b'),('A'),('B')) x(n)
 order by n collate "en_US";

 n 
---
 a
 A
 b
 B
```

---

Per comments you're using MacOS, which uses quite different sort rules than GNU's libc, and among other differences, does not mix upper and lower case.

So in a way this question is close to: [How can I achieve the same Postgres collation behavior in Linux as that in Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328592) which has currently no  positive answer.

Aside from sorting on `lower(field)` instead of `field`, in theory you could build your own collation file, feed it to [`colldef`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/colldef.1.html), and then it would become available to every program that uses the system's sort according the the `LC_COLLATE` setting, including PostgreSQL.

In practice I don't see the source files shipped with Apple OS to begin with, and starting this file from scratch seems unreasonably hard.

Comment: What is your encoding? I does not work this way in my database. <br /> select * from test1 order by name collate "en_US"<br />A<br />B<br />a<br />b<br />(4 rows)<br />

Comment: @Yang: the encoding is UTF8 but please state your exact operating system so that your results can be interpreted in context.

Comment: Mac OS@Daniel Vérité