# Comparing strings in postgres using comparison operators?

Tags: postgresql, natural-sort

In many programming languages you can compare strings using operators like >, >=, < etc...and the language will base the comparison on the position of the letter in the alphabet.

For example in PHP

```
if ('a' < 'b') {
    echo 'Yes';
} else {
    echo 'No';
}
> Yes
```

However in postgres or mysql

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN 'a' < 'b' THEN 'yes' END
FROM table
Output: null
```

I have a table with strings that I need to compare against each other through SQL.

For example:
6.2(5a) 
6.2(5b) -- this would be greater than 6.2(5a)
Or 
6.2(15) -- this would be greater than 6.2(5a)

I thought of assigning a number to a letter using a regexp but then that would break the comparisons when there are no letter.

How would you go about this purely in SQL?

Comment: `select 'a' < 'b';` in postgres 9.6.1 results in True. `select '6.2(5a)' < '6.2(5b)';` returns True. `select '6.2(15)' < '6.2(5a)';` returns True also. The last one is true because `6.2(` are matching. The next character `'1' < '5'` and that makes 6.2(15) smaller than 6.2(5a). Isn't that your expectation?

Comment: Okay actually that seems to be the issue.  The latter comparison of select '6.2(15)' < '6.2(5a)' returning true.  I didn't notice that until you pointed it out.  So I guess the issue now becomes how to ensure that '15' would be greater than '5a'  maybe test for letters first, remove them and test for the number string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL ORDER BY issue - natural sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173558/postgresql-order-by-issue-natural-sort)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

***NOTE***: *The original answer went off on a red herring*.

A simple comparison sorts character by character.

```
select 'a1' < 'a9'; -- true because 'a' = 'a' and '1' < '9'.
```

...but quickly goes to pot.

```
select 'a10' < 'a9'; -- also true for the same reason.
```

What you want is a [natural sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order) where the string parts are compared as strings and the numbers are compared as numbers. Doing a natural sort in SQL is not the easiest thing. You either need fixed field widths to sort each substring separately, or maybe something with regexes...

Fortunately there's [pg_natural_sort_order](https://github.com/Bjond/pg_natural_sort_order), a Postgres extension that implements an efficient natural sort.

If you can't install extensions you can use a stored procedure like [btrsort](http://2kan.tumblr.com/post/361326656/postgres-natural-ordering) by 2kan.

```
CREATE FUNCTION btrsort_nextunit(text) RETURNS text AS $$
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN $1 ~ '^[^0-9]+' THEN
            COALESCE( SUBSTR( $1, LENGTH(SUBSTRING($1 FROM '[^0-9]+'))+1 ), '' )
        ELSE
            COALESCE( SUBSTR( $1, LENGTH(SUBSTRING($1 FROM '[0-9]+'))+1 ), '' )
        END

$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE FUNCTION btrsort(text) RETURNS text AS $$
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN char_length($1)>0 THEN
            CASE WHEN $1 ~ '^[^0-9]+' THEN
                RPAD(SUBSTR(COALESCE(SUBSTRING($1 FROM '^[^0-9]+'), ''), 1, 12), 12, ' ') || btrsort(btrsort_nextunit($1))
            ELSE
                LPAD(SUBSTR(COALESCE(SUBSTRING($1 FROM '^[0-9]+'), ''), 1, 12), 12, ' ') || btrsort(btrsort_nextunit($1))
            END
        ELSE
            $1
        END
      ;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Though it doesn't provide a comparison operator and I'm not going to pretend to understand it. This allows you to use it in an `order by`.

```
select * from things order by btrsort(whatever);
```

To prevent your naturally sorted queries from turning to mud on large tables, [you can create a btree index on the result of that function](http://postgresql.nabble.com/Natural-sort-order-td5082405.html).

```
create index things_whatever_btrsort_idx ON things( btrsort(whatever) );
```

---

> ```
> SELECT
>   CASE WHEN 'a' < 'b' THEN 'yes' END
>   FROM table
>   Output: null
> ```

This will only output nothing if the table is empty. You don't need a table to test select statements.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN 'a' < 'b' THEN 'yes' END  -- yes
```

Comment: This is great information, unfortunately this is postgres running in a greenplum and its a closed system.  I can't install extensions.

Comment: @bakamike I added an alternative using stored procedures.

Comment: after new updates psql will deliver select 'a' < 'z'; also true, it will be nice, if you update your answer

Comment: @MichealToru `select 'a' < 'z';` is already true. Do you mean `select 'a' < 'Z';`? Which update made the change?

Comment: yas i do. its also true

Comment: @MichealToru Hmm. `select 'a' < 'Z';` is true on dbfiddle, but false on my local Postgres 11.7 on OS X from Macports. I think what I'm actually testing is [collation differences between Mac and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328592/how-can-i-achieve-the-same-postgres-collation-behavior-in-linux-as-that-in-mac-o). I don't have a Postgres 12 on my Mac to see if they fixed it at the moment, I'm traveling.

Comment: @MichealToru Turns out the first half of the answer was a red herring. I've stripped it out. Thanks for the note.

Comment: I know this answer is already a bit older but maybe you can help. If I do in javascript `'c28xzxe29h' <= 'c28x~'` it evaluates to `true` (the value I am expecting). However, in postgres doing `select 'c28xzxe29h' <= 'c28x~';` evaluates to `false`. Any idea why postgres behaves differently here? And is there any workaround (replacing `~` with something else) to get the expected result?

Comment: @fkrauthan  That is strange. Probably be a collation issue, but I don't have an answer. Ask that as a question and @ me in the comments,

Comment: Ok done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74790306/postgres-and-behaviors-with-special-characters